# Why is it possible to connect to the redis docker container without port forwarding?

Tags: docker, redis

When I run: `docker run --rm -it redis`, The container receives `ip: 172.18.0.2`. Then from the host I connect to the container with the following command: `redis-cli -h 172.18.0.2`, and it connects normally, everything works, the keys are added. Why does this happen without port forwarding? Default docker network - bridge

Answer (score 0):

`docker run --rm -it redis` will not expose the port. Try stop the redis container. Then run `redis-cli -h 172.18.0.2` to check if another redis exists.

Comment: When I stop redis container I cannot connect to it!

Comment: Docker auto add iptables rule to do the port export, maybe the rule keep exists. Try restart docker service daemon to clear the rules, then restart redis with `docker run --rm -it redis`. Do the test again.

Comment: I restarted service daemon (systemctl reload docker, systemctl restart docker). And i still connect without port publishing... It looks like a bug...

Comment: I do the test with my mac and Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962. It works well and the port not exported. Maybe some reason I do not know.

Comment: restart docker service do not clear the iptables rules that created manually. You can clear iptables rules then try again.

Comment: you can check https://serverfault.com/questions/200635/best-way-to-clear-all-iptables-rules

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible because you're on native Linux, and the way Docker networking is implemented, it happens to be possible to directly connect to the container-private IP addresses from outside Docker.

This doesn't work in a wide variety of common situations (on MacOS or Windows hosts; if Docker is actually running in a VM; if you're making the call from a different host) and the IP address you get can change if the container is recreated.  As such it's not usually a best practice to look up the container-private IP address.  Use `docker run -p` to publish a port, and connect to that published port and the host's IP address.

Comment: But i cannot connect to nginx container in the same way without port publishing. Why does it work with redis?

Answer (score -1):

It's because the redis [docker file](https://hub.docker.com/layers/redis/library/redis/latest/images/sha256-6b0e68dedce960fc79b45da55e94fcf405a7d43c89721ca4078836c2cbe336cb?context=explore) exposes the right port for the api which is 6379.

Comment: The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.  [Docker documentation]

Comment: Hi, expose will enable another container to connect via that port, so if you are running redis-cli from another container then it will work.

Comment: Expose is only a documentation thing. You can start nginx container without publishing port (docker run --rm -it nginx) but you can not connect to it.